# JAXB and MOXy xml and json marshalling of generic list in jersey

Tags: jaxb, jersey, jax-rs, moxy

I'm making a little restful client in Jersey, and i have come into a little trouble with supporting both XML and JSON marshaling.

The specific problem is about marshaling an object that holds a few properties, with a generic list included.

I have the following class annotated as followed:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Block<E> {

    private String headerText;

    private List<E> elements;

    public Block() {
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getHeaderText() {
        return headerText;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "elements")
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "element", type=Foo.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "element", type=Bar.class)
    })
    public List<E> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }
}
```

The XML comes out fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<block>
<elements>
    <element>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>Title01</title>
    </element>
    <element>
        <id>2</id>>
        <title>Title02</title>
    </element>
</elements>
<headerText>FooBarHeader</headerText>
</block>
```

but the JSON is formatted like this

```
{
-elements : {
    -element: [
         - {
            id : 1
            title : "Title01"
        }
         - {
            id : 2
            title : "Title02"
        }
    ]
}
headerText : "HeaderText"
}
```

I would of course be interested in not having the "element" property in my JSON output, and only have `elements: [{}...{}]`

I have already setup a `ContextResolver` that creates a `MOXyConfig` with properties for `JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME` - and this works fine for fx. A `List<String>` where I only have to declare the property with `@XmlElement` instead of `@XmlElements`.

Anyone who know of a solution of this problem?

Comment: Normally the `@XmlElement` annotations within an `@XmlElements` annotation have different names.  I notice you gave them the same name, is this intentional?  Are `Foo` and `Bar` part of the same inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: In this basic template code, i just used copy/paste, hence the same names in the @XmlElement annotation. Foo and Bar is potentially two completely different classes, and could have no relation to one another.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. For me it looks like a moxy bug. Did you already track it or solved this issue by any workaround?

Comment: We have chosen to throw xml out of the window, and just use jackson as a provider instead. Jackson works like a charm, actually it's much easier to work with in my opinion.

Comment: A similar problem can arise with `@XmlElementRef`. I opened a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493237) before I found your question here. Unfortunately, it seems like MOXy is dormant, to say the least. :-(

Answer (score 1):

### `JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME` Property

The effect of the `JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME` property (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/binding-to-json-xml-handling-collections.html) depends on whether the item names are significant or not,

**Insignificant Item Names**

Below we know that each item in the collection is an instance of `Foo` or an instance of a subclass of `Foo`.

```java
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "elements")
@XmlElement(name = "element")
public List<E> getElements() {
    return elements;
}
```

**Significant Item Names**

In the case of `@XmlElements` the item name is significant since it tells us which class we need to instantiate on the unmarshal and can not be excluded.

```java
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "elements")
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "foo", type=Foo.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "bar", type=Bar.class)
})
public List<E> getElements() {
    return elements;
}
```

### What You Can Do

You can use MOXy's externmal mapping document to override the mapping for the elements property to the following:

```java
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "elements")
@XmlElement(name = "foo")
public List<E> getElements() {
    return elements;
}
```

Then the `JAXBContext` for XML will be based on the annotations, and the `JAXBContext` for JSON will be based on the annotatons and external mapping document.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

Comment: Did not solve my problem. The JSON output format is still the same as showed in the topic, just with "foo" or "bar" as property name instead of "element". Cheers though

Answer (score 1):

Try registering another JSON Entity Provider, which will disable automatically Moxy for JSON marshalling ([see the ref](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy)). If you enable e.g Jackson, you will have its own annotations to control how everything is marshalled.

Comment: I registered jackson, and this works fine. I would just like to only have to apply one type of annotations, instead of two, since i have to support both xml and json. Marked as a useful answer though. Thanks :)